# Unable to add Azure APIs from WSDL defination

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to add API from WSDL.
https://ecs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/Handouts/cse775/code/calcWebService/Calc.asmx?WSDL

[image]

Below error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If API Management is not able to access urls in the namespace, the import will fail:

[Error while importing WSDL to APIM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/01653a97-ce5d-400b-a34d-23e39b8c2c29/error-while-importing-wsdl-to-apim?forum=azureapimgmt):

> This can happen when your wsdl is referencing schemas with location that APIM can not discover.
>
> 1. You might need to make it a complete wsdl by hand so that its not referencing anything thats unreachable.
> 2. Or upload the imported schamas to a blob storage and then you can edit the wsdl to point to this location.

In your case, this namespace URL does not work:
`xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"`

[image]

This namespace is not used in the WSDL. So you can do following workaround:

- Download the WSDL file
- Remove `xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"` from the local file.
- Upload the local file to APIM:

[image]

[image]

If possible, please remove this namespace from the webservice.